# Spectral theorem for compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Given an operator $T \in B(H)$, denote its spectrum by $\sigma(T)$. We write $\Omega := \sigma(T)\setminus \{0\}$. The following result is well-known and ***can be assumed without proof***:

> Let $T \in B_0(H)$ be a self-adjoint compact operator on a Hilbert
> space $H$. Given $\lambda \in \Omega$, let $P_\lambda$ be the
> finite-rank projection on $\mathcal{E}_\lambda:= \ker(T-\lambda I)$.
> Then $$T= \sum_{\lambda \in \Omega} \lambda P_\lambda$$ where the
> unordered sum converges in the norm topology.

Given $\xi, \eta \in H$, let us define the rank-one operator $R_{\xi, \eta}: H \to H$ by $R_{\xi, \eta}(\zeta):= \langle \zeta, \eta\rangle \xi$. I want to prove the following theorem:

> If $T \in B_0(H)$ is a self-adjoint operator compact operator, then
> there is an orthonormal basis $\{e_s\}_{s \in S}$ for $\ker(T)^\perp$
> and a collection $\{\mu_s\}_{s \in S} \in c_0(S)$ such that  $$T=
>  \sum_{s \in S} \mu_s R_{e_s, e_s}$$ where the series converges in
> norm. In particular, a self-adjoint compact operator admits an
> orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

The idea of the proof should be more or less the following:

We have an orthogonal direct sum decomposition $$\ker(T)^\perp = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in \Omega} \mathcal{E}_\lambda$$
Given $\lambda \in \Omega$, let $\mathcal{F}_\lambda$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{E}_\lambda$. Then we have $$P_\lambda = \sum_{\xi \in \mathcal{F}_\lambda} R_{\xi, \xi}$$ and it follows that
$$T = \sum_{\lambda \in \Omega}\lambda \left(\sum_{\xi \in \mathcal{F}_\lambda} R_{\xi, \xi}\right) = \sum_{\lambda \in \Omega}\left(\sum_{\xi \in \mathcal{F}_\lambda} \lambda R_{\xi, \xi}\right)= \sum_{\xi \in \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Omega} \mathcal{F}_\lambda} \lambda R_{\xi, \xi}$$
Then $\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Omega} \mathcal{E}_\lambda$ is an orthonormal basis for $\ker(T)^\perp$ and this should yield the desired decomposition. However, I feel like the equality
$$\sum_{\lambda \in \Omega}\left(\sum_{\xi \in \mathcal{F}_\lambda} \lambda R_{\xi, \xi}\right)= \sum_{\xi \in \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Omega} \mathcal{F}_\lambda} \lambda R_{\xi, \xi}$$
still requires some formal justification. We should at least show that the sum on the right converges in the norm topology! Of course, other approaches to prove my end goal are also welcome!

EDIT: It's a strong requirement to me that the convergence of all series involved is in the norm-topology. Many references only deal with the strong convergence of these series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's precisely where you get to use that your $T$ is compact.

Fix $\delta>0$, and consider $\Omega_\delta=\{\lambda\in\Omega:\ \lambda>\delta\}$. Suppose $\Omega_\delta$ is infinite. For each $\lambda\in\Omega_\delta$, fix $h_\lambda\in P_\lambda H$ with $\|h_\lambda\|=1$. The set $\{h_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Omega_\delta}$ is orthonormal; we can write $Th_\lambda=\lambda h_\lambda$ as
$$
T(\frac1\lambda\,h_\lambda)=h_\lambda. 
$$
As $\lambda>\delta$, we have that $\tfrac1\lambda\,h_\lambda$ sits inside the ball of radius $1/\delta$. So $\{h_\lambda\}$ is in the image through $T$ of the ball of radius $1/\delta$. And, being orthonormal, $\{h_\lambda\}$ does not have a convergent subsequence, contradicint the compactness of $T$. We have thus shown that $\Omega_\delta$ is finite. Note that this argument also implies that each $P_\lambda$ is finite-rank.

By consider the finite sets $\Omega_{1/n}$, we prove that $\Omega$ consists of a sequence that converges to $0$, as desired.

If $\{\xi_n\}$ is a finite orthonormal set and $P_n$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbb C\xi_n$, then
$$\tag1
\Big\|\sum_n\lambda_n\,P_n\Big\|=\sup\{|\lambda_n|:\ n\}. 
$$
Indeed, if $\xi\in H$ with $\|\xi\|=1$, then $\xi=\eta+\sum_n c_n\xi_n$, where $\eta$ is orthogonal to all $\xi_n$. Then (since $P_n\eta=0$ for all $n$)
\begin{align}
\Big\|\sum_n\lambda_nP_n\xi\Big\|^2
&=\Big\|\sum_n\sum_k\lambda_nc_kP_n\xi_k\Big\|^2
=\Big\|\sum_n\lambda_nc_n\xi_n\Big\|^2
=\sum_n|\lambda_n|^2\,|c_n|^2\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\sup\{|\lambda_n|:\ n\}\,\sum_n|c_n|^2\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\{|\lambda_n|:\ n\}.
\end{align}
Using that $\Big\|\sum_n\lambda_nP_n\xi_k\Big\|=|\lambda_k|$ it is then easy to check the equality $(1)$.

Now allow the set $\{\xi_n\}$ to be infinite. If $\lambda_n\to0$, fix $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $n_0$ such that $|\lambda_k|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Then
$$
\Big\|\sum_{k=n}^m\lambda_kP_k\Big\|=\sup\{|\lambda_k|:\ k\geq n\}\leq\varepsilon
$$
for all $m>n\geq n_0$. This shows that the tails of the series $\sum_n\lambda_nP_n$ go to zero, and so the series converges.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question. The crux is to show norm-convergence of a certain series, about which your answer doesn't say anything. All the things in this answer I already knew and can prove.

Comment: You wrote "I want to prove the following theorem" and you gave no indication that you knew how to prove that the sequence was c_0$.

Comment: I might not have said it explicitly, but it is immediate from the first theorem I used. Since the sum converges, the eigenvalues must go to zero.

Comment: Right, but you have to use that the eigenvalues go to zero, to show that the sum converges in norm (it doesn't, otherwise).

Comment: Yes of course, but my question was how to use the first theorem I mention (you can assume this to be true) to prove the second theorem. Nothing in your answer adresses the actual question, though I appreciate the effort. I guess maybe I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. More than half my answer is the proof that the sum converges in norm. What else are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: Apologies. I was confused because you used the $P_n$ notation (and I assumed this were the same $P_n$'s as in the first theorem I mentioned). I will have a detailed look!

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice. I just felt that your $T_{\xi,\xi}$ and $S_{\xi,\xi}$ were a bit cumbersome to type, and they hide the fact that we are dealing with sequences.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I'm going over your answer in detail tomorrow but it looks exactly what I need!

Comment: Perhaps one comment. I want the result for unordered sums, while you proved it for ordered sums (which is weaker). Maybe we can use the fact that if a sum converges for all orderings, then also the unordered sum converges? Or I think we can simply adapt the argument given here and prove it immediately for the unordered sum.

Comment: There's nothing "ordered" about the argument. Conditional convergence is a phenomenon that mostly happens with the naive definition of series on the real line. Here all we are using is that the sequence of coefficients converges to zero, which happens regardless order. If you feel uncomfortable about it, just replace $n>n_0$ with "$n$ outside of a given finite set $F$" and the argument (which doesn't change) is unordered.

Comment: Thanks the answer works perfectly! I posted my interpretation of your answer below in an own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proof how I wrote it down:

**Theorem**: Let $T \in B_0(H)$ is a self-adjoint operator compact operator. If $\mathcal{F}_\lambda$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{E}_\lambda$ for each $\lambda \in \Omega$, then $\mathcal{F} = \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Omega} \mathcal{F}_\lambda$ is an orthonormal basis for $\ker(T)^\perp$ and we can write
$$T= \sum_{\xi \in \mathcal{F}} \lambda_\xi R_{\xi,\xi}$$
where $\lambda_\xi = \lambda$ when $\xi \in \mathcal{F}_\lambda$ where the series converges in norm.

**Proof**: Since eigenvectors belonging to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal, it is clear that the family $\mathcal{F}$ is orthonormal. Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the closed linear span of $\mathcal{F}$. Clearly $\mathcal{K} \perp \ker(T)$. The operator $T\vert_{(\mathcal{K}\oplus \ker(T))^\perp}$ is self-adjoint and compact. If $(\mathcal{K}\oplus \ker(T))^\perp \ne 0$, it would follow that $T$ has a non-zero eigenvector $\zeta \in (\mathcal{K}\oplus \ker(T))^\perp$. But all eigenvectors are contained in $\mathcal{K}\oplus \ker(T)$, so this is impossible. Hence, the orthogonal complement must be zero and we conclude that $\mathcal{K}\oplus \ker(T) = \mathcal{H}$, i.e. $\ker(T)^\perp = \mathcal{K}$ and hence $\mathcal{F}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\ker(T)^\perp$.

Given $\xi\in \mathcal{F}$, define $\lambda_\xi:= \lambda$ where $\lambda \in \Omega$ is the unique eigenvalue with $\xi \in \mathcal{F}_\lambda$ We prove that the series $\sum_{\xi \in \mathcal{F}} \lambda_\xi R_{\xi,\xi}$ necessarily converges.

Consider the finite set $F_0:= \{\xi \in \mathcal{F}: |\lambda_\xi|\ge \epsilon\}$. If $F$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal{F}$ with $F \cap F_0 = \emptyset$, then
$$\left\|\sum_{\xi \in F} \lambda_\xi R_{\xi,\xi}\right\| = \max_{\xi \in F} |\lambda_{\xi}| < \epsilon$$
and it follows that $T':= \sum_{\xi \in \mathcal{F}}\lambda_\xi R_{\xi,\xi} \in B_0(\mathcal{H})$ converges in norm.

It remains to show that $T' = T.$ But it is clear that $T\xi = T'\xi$ for all $\xi \in \mathcal{F}$ and that $T\vert_{\ker(T)}= 0 = T'\vert_{\ker(T)}$, so this readily follows.